# How to release the hugepages allocated by DPDK application?

Tags: dpdk, page-tables, huge-pages

I am using DPDK-PROX application. Whenever I am closing that application, hugepages allocated by that application are not released. Every time I have to restart the system. Any solution?

I looked into below question but my issue is not resolved.

[How to release hugepages from the crashed application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366181/how-to-release-hugepages-from-the-crashed-application) 
[How to really free hugepages in Linux for use by a new process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303681/how-to-really-free-hugepages-in-linux-for-use-by-a-new-process) 
[Proper Way to Release a Hugepage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56546543/proper-way-to-release-a-hugepage)

This is what is what i see in /proc/meminfo

```
    AnonHugePages:         0 kB
    ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
    HugePages_Total:    1024
    HugePages_Free:        0
    HugePages_Rsvd:        0
    HugePages_Surp:        0
    Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
```

Answer (score 4):

The behavior you are seeing is characteristic of DPDK versions before 18.05, or 18.05+ with `--legacy-mem` parameter. I'm going to assume the former as that is more likely.

This is happening because DPDK supports a certain flavor of multiprocessing, which allows "secondary" processes to attach to a "primary" process, even after it has already exited. Since DPDK relies on hugepage files (in `hugetlbfs` filesystem) to share memory between its primary and secondary processes, these hugepage files are not deleted after application exit, to allow secondary processes to use them.

There are multiple solutions to this problem. First one - you may not need to do anything at all. If you fear that DPDK will not be able to start again because you've run out of hugepages, then this is not an issue, because DPDK will clear out any unused hugepages before allocating new ones.

If you want to release this memory back to the system after shutting down the process, you may want to do so manually. To do that, you have to know where the hugepages were stored (i.e. where is your `hugetlbfs` mounted) - on many distros, it is mounted at `/dev/hugepages` by default. If you go there and clear out all of the `rte_*` files (assuming you're using default DPDK prefix, which you probably do), all of the hugepages will be freed back to the system.

Finally, if you don't care about multiprocessing, you may use `--huge-unlink` EAL parameter[1] when running DPDK. This will make it so that whatever hugepages DPDK allocates, it will remove the files right afterwards. Then, when application closes, the hugepages will be automatically released by virtue of closing the file handles.

In newer versions of DPDK, this is less of a problem, because DPDK can dynamically scale its memory usage up and down [2]. I'm not familiar with DPDK-PROX so i cannot say if it supports newer DPDK versions.

[1] https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/memory-in-dpdk-part-3-1711-and-earlier-releases

[2] https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/memory-in-dpdk-part-4-1811-and-beyond

Comment: When we use `--huge-unlink` - can DPDK pass it's huge pages file descriptors over UNIX socket?

Comment: If you're asking if it's at all technically possible to do so, then yes. If you're asking if DPDK is programed to do that, then no. So, it *can*, but it won't :)